# How to make components render with parameters in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Ok, don't bash me if I'm stupid. I'm studying Angular 2 with its components, directives and so on. I got the basic parts but I want to go to the next level. So as an example, suppose I have a customer component, which shows the data of a customer. It will be used in many parts of the app. So the silly question: How do I pass the customer to it? I mean, wherever it shows it will be about a certain customer and instead of only showing the customer's name, I wanted a button that would show an expandable div with the customer data. But how is it done?

Comment: I think I got my way onto it. Components can have parameters, its more or less like: export class CustomerComponent {
  @Input() customerCode = 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

to pass parameters to componets you can use @Input

when you call the compenent you can pass the parameter as follow

```html
<customer-detail [customer]="parentCustomer"></customer-detail>
```

and to receive in the component controller:

```
export class CustomerDetailCmpt{
    @Input() customer: any;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to fiture it out! I'm still struggling with Angular 2, its still very "alien" to me. Gonna ask some more and hopefully you guys can help me up! Thank you again!

Comment: you're welcome, if you just started I recommend you to follow the tour of heroes tutorial: [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial)